# Group & Sum rows using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm using the following to process rows from shopping cart. I'm wanting to group the rows and sum the values in the grouping. I'm not able to get the sum to work at all and I was hoping to get some assistance please.

thanks in advance

-- data

```
var cart: [
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Batteries',
        description: 'AAA size batteries',
        price: 10.99
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Beacons',
        description: 'Bluetooth long life beacons',
        price: 30.00
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Beacons',
        description: 'Bluetooth long life beacons',
        price: 30.00
      }
    ]
```

-- code

```
 const groupedResult = _(cart)
    .groupBy('price')
    .map(function(items, price, title) {
      return {
        title: _.map(items, 'title'),
        description: _.map(items, 'description'),
         price: _.sum(price, 'price'),
      };
    }).value()
```

-- current output

```
    {title: Array(2), description: Array(2), price: "30"}
    {title: Array(1), description: Array(1), price: "10.99"}
```

-- expected output

```
   {title: 'Beacons', description: 'Bluetooth long life beacons', price: '30.00', total: '60.00', quantity: 2}
   {title: 'Batteries', description: 'AAA size batteries', price: '10.99', total: '10.99', quantity: 1}
```

Comment: how do you want to group it?

Comment: do you want to group by id and sum all prices?

Comment: yes I do. I tried various ways to do this but I kept getting o or undefined for the prices.

Comment: guijob I realise this, I thought that I might be able to map the prices and then sum inside the map like : price: ._map(.sum(price, 'price'))

Comment: include your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array into a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), and sum the prices if an `id` already exists on the Map. Then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the [`Map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) back to an array:

```js
const cart = [{"id":2,"title":"Batteries","description":"AAA size batteries","price":10.99},{"id":1,"title":"Beacons","description":"Bluetooth long life beacons","price":30},{"id":1,"title":"Beacons","description":"Bluetooth long life beacons","price":30}];
    
const result = [...cart.reduce((r, o) => {
  // add a new item to the map, and set price and quantity to 0
  r.has(o.id) || r.set(o.id, Object.assign({}, o, { price: 0, quantity: 0 }));
  
  // get current item;
  const item = r.get(o.id);
  
  // add current price to item
  item.price += o.price;
  
  // increment quantity
  item.quantity++;

  return r;
}, new Map()).values()]; // spread the values iterator back to array

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

[`groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#groupBy) returns an object instead of an array, but you can get this values using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) once you unwrap your result using [`Array.from()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#prototype-Symbol-iterator). So, assuming `title`, `description` and `price` with same values for same `id`, this should work:

```
 const groupedResult = Object.values(Array.from(_(cart)
 .groupBy('id')))
 .map(x => ({
   title: x[0].title,
   description: x[0].description,
   price: x[0].price,
   quantity: x.length,
   total: _.sumBy(x, x => x.price)
 }));
```

Note: [`sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sumBy) is only available in `lodash` 4.0.0 and above.